# About the release time of the Indigo Desktop version?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is supposed to be released in last month......cant wait~~~~~~  lol

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174457/about-the-release-time-of-the-indigo-desktop-version?/) by [梓喵](https://answers.ros.org/users/11491/%E6%A2%93%E5%96%B5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not yet a specific release data -- discussions of blockers are currently happening on the ros-release mailing list (http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-release)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0